# One radio button group across multiple forms

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

Given the bellow code the buttons will behave as checkboxes. Is there any regular approach to to keep their single select property and keep them split across different forms?
The multiple form is a must in my case because I split the same radio button group among forms which are nested in HTML table rows.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" id="update" name="update"> 
        </form>
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" id="update" name="update"> 
        </form>
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" id="update" name="update"> 
        </form>
    </td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Pro-tip: Don't use tables. **Ever**. Unless you need to display something like statistics, but not for a User Interface.

The forms here probably won't be linked at all. You need to have them within the same form, I think. That is the only logical answer I can give.

Edit:
Also, while you can have multiple inputs with the same `name`, you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: Thx for your feedback but even if I will use the div rows there will also be on form per row and the html table is here just as an en example. I have already replaced the radio input with submit buttons to get rid of the no sense multi select. I am surprised that the HTML designers didn't think about this case. Your point about unique id makes sense.

Comment: @ronline What you could do is wrap a single form around the whole container of rows, in this case around the entire `table`. This way your example with multiple radio buttons across different rows would work.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution but we are getting out of scope here. I know it can be done this way but the point is how to spread button group across multiple forms. I am ok with it if HTML doesn't handle such a case by design. However I am surprised the engineers didn't think about this.